# jquery client restful service jax rs

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, web-services, spring-mvc

I'm trying to call a restfull web service with spring mvc and jquery. The service is up, but i think that my jquery call isn´t correct.  In the network javascript console I have a status code : 200 ok, and the response is the string hello world, but the console says:

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

And shows a sintax error at the begin of the return message:  (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier).

I think that it could be data type  return problem, but i dont know how to solve it.

This is the jquery call:

```
function hellowsfunction() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',


        url:"http://localhost:8080/ehCS-ui/rest/hello/helloWorld",
        headers : {Accept : "applicationjson","Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"},
            success: function(msg) {

             $("#lblResult")
            .text(result)
            .slideUp("hide", function() { $(this).slideDown("slow") });
     },
      error: function (e) { 
            $("#lblResult").removeClass("loading");
            alert('failed:'+e);
            console.log(e);
             }
     });

    }
```

And this is the web service:

```
@Controller


@RequestMapping("/hello")

public class HelloWs {

    @RequestMapping(value= "/helloWorld", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    @ResponseBody
    public String HelloWorld() {

            return "Hello World";

        }
```

Please help me!! 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused. In your question you asking about JAX-RS, but in your code it seems that you are using Spring MVC which is not a JAX-RS implementation.

So I'll answer the question if it was about JAX-RS. In JAX-RS you need to put `@Produces` annotation on your resource declaring the correct media type. It can be global for the whole class or for a specific method.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I'm using spring mvc whith their anotations. In jax rs it should be the @produces anotation, but I dont know how spring MVC consumes the data. Can you help me?

Comment: No. Sorry. I suggest to change the question and also the tags